# Need Correct var for the Current Image Being Displayed

Tags: slider, jssor

I am trying to access the current img src being displayed in a jssor_slider, but cannot seem to find the var. I think it is in the mini.js file but that's a pain to sift through. Is there a public var that holds the current img src being displayed that I can pass to another script?

Answer (score 0):

get current slide index with

```
jssor_slider_1.$CurrentIndex();
```

See [API](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html)